# Error "undefined method `to_datetime'" in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, sidekiq

Start sidekiq with the command

```
bundle exec sidekiq -e production -P /path/to/pid/file/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid -L /path/to/log/file/shared/log/sidekiq.log --daemon
```

In the log error

```
2017-06-29T06:59:44.776Z 16181 TID-1jr7pg ERROR: CRON JOB: undefined method `to_datetime' for #<EtOrbi::EoTime:0x0000000a933848>
2017-06-29T06:59:44.776Z 16181 TID-1jr7pg ERROR: CRON JOB: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@script-admin/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:141:in `<=>'
```

error while executing the method `/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@script-admin/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:141:in <=>`:

```
def <=> (other)
  super other.kind_of?(Infinity) ? other : other.to_datetime
end
```

What can be done with the problem?

---

**UPD:** Updated version rails to `3.2.22.5` and there is a new error

```
ERROR: CRON JOB: comparison of Time with EtOrbi::EoTime failed
ERROR: CRON JOB: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@script-admin/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.3.1/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:434:in `<'
```

in this place

```
def not_enqueued_after?(time)
  @last_enqueue_time.nil? || @last_enqueue_time < last_time(time)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue arises not from sidekiq but from Rails 3.2.13. `#<=>` does not handle `undefined method to_datetime`. It was fixed in future versions of Rails. For example, in the Rails 3.2.22.5:

```
def <=>(other)
  if other.kind_of?(Infinity)
    super
  elsif other.respond_to? :to_datetime
    super other.to_datetime
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Therefore, the simplest way to solve your issue is to update your Rails version. If it is not an options paste your code or rewrite `#<=>`.

Comment: thanks, but now `comparison of Time with EtOrbi::EoTime failed`

Answer (score 1):

`to_datetime` is a method from rails' [activesupport library](https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime) and your sidekiq worker is not using this.

try adding `require 'active_support/core_ext'` to your sidekiq initializer config `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` and restart sidekiq

Comment: seems like the comparision is failing because you are trying to compare time object from the gem `EtOrbi::EoTime` with ruby's standard `DateTime` object

Comment: to be honest, I can't do debugging :)